Laravel 11: Livewire not updating calendar and modal properly
I am using Laravel 11 and created a livewire InvoiceDetail from detail blade which is accessible through /invooice/{id} route
It contains  an individual Invoice id but shows list of all invoices for current user and selected and month

The year and month dropdown allow to filter data on changing options.
The calendar and modal open button are clickable/activated only if invoice has status unpaid (the status is unpaid even if minimum one invoice in the list is unpaid)
I am facing one issue:
Initially everything works fine
When year/month are changed,the list gets refreshed , and we get the list where no invoice is found or invoice is found but with paid/transfer status (here calendar and modal are not clickable)
now when we change the year/month and get the list where status is unpaid,  calendar and modal seems to be working but both are not working in this particular case.
Everything are done without reloading the page here.
my InvoiceDetail.php is :
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Invoice;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Mail\InvoicePaymentTransferred;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class InvoiceDetail extends Component
{
    public $year = '';
    public $month = '';
    public $years = [];
    public $invoice;
    public $paymentDate = [];
    public $relatedInvoices;
    public $errorMessage;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.invoice-detail');
    }

    public function mount(Invoice $invoice)
    {
        $this->loadData($invoice);
        $this->fetchRelatedInvoices();
    }

    public function loadData($invoice)
    {
        $this->invoice = $invoice;
        // Set default values for year, month, and payment date
        $this->year = $invoice->date->format('Y');
        $this->month = $invoice->date->format('n');
        if (empty($this->paymentDate)) {
            $this->paymentDate = $invoice->is_paid == 0
                ? now()->format('Y年m月d日')
                : Carbon::parse($invoice->payment_date)->format('Y年m月d日');
        }

        $this->years = $this->generateYears();
    }

    public function generateYears()
    {
        $years = Invoice::selectRaw('YEAR(date) as year')
            ->distinct()
            ->pluck('year')
            ->toArray();

        if (empty($years)) {
            $years = [now()->year, now()->subYear()->year, now()->subYears(2)->year];
        }

        // Sort the years in ascending order
        sort($years);

        // Get the minimum and maximum years
        $minYear = min($years);
        $maxYear = max($years);

        // Generate a range of years, including all years between the min and max
        $years = range($minYear, $maxYear);

        return $years;
    }

    public function transferPayment($invoiceId)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            $invoice = Invoice::findOrFail($invoiceId);
            $paymentDate = $this->paymentDate ? Carbon::createFromFormat('Y年m月d日', $this->paymentDate)->format('Y-m-d') : null;

            // Find all unpaid invoices for the user and the given year and month
            $invoices = Invoice::where('user_id', $invoice->user_id)
                ->whereYear('date', $invoice->date->year)
                ->whereMonth('date', $invoice->date->month)
                ->where('is_paid', "0") // Only invoices that are not paid
                ->get();
            // Update all invoices' payment status to transfer and payment date
            foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
                $invoice->is_paid = "1";  // Mark as paid
                $invoice->payment_date = $paymentDate ? Carbon::parse($paymentDate) : Carbon::now();  // Set payment date
                $invoice->save();
            }

            // Send email to the master's email
            // Try to get admin email from config, if not available, fall back to the user's email
            $adminEmail = config('companyinfos.admin_mail');

            // If admin email from config is not available, get it from the db
            if (empty($adminEmail)) {
                $user = User::where('role_id', 1)->first();
                $userInfo = $user ? $user->userInfo : null;
                if ($userInfo && $userInfo->email) {
                    $adminEmail = $userInfo->email;
                }
            }

            // Send email to the determined admin email
            if ($adminEmail) {
                // Mail::to($adminEmail)->send(new InvoicePaymentTransferred($invoice));
            }

            // Commit the transaction
            DB::commit();

            // Refresh the invoice
            $this->mount($invoice);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // If any exception occurs, rollback the transaction
            DB::rollBack();
            $this->errorMessage = __('Invoice payment could not be transferred.');
        }
    }

    public function updated($field)
    {
        $this->fetchRelatedInvoices();
        if (in_array($field, ['year', 'month']) && $this->invoice != null) {
            $this->paymentDate = $this->invoice->payment_date ? Carbon::parse($this->invoice->payment_date)->format('Y年m月d日') : now()->format('Y年m月d日');
        }
    }

    public function fetchRelatedInvoices()
    {
        $query = Invoice::where('user_id', auth()->id());

        if ($this->year) {
            $query->whereYear('date', $this->year);
        }

        if ($this->month) {
            $query->whereMonth('date', $this->month);
        }

        $this->relatedInvoices = $query->with('survey')->orderBy('updated_at', 'asc')->get();

        // Ensure $this->invoice is not null before accessing its properties
        if ($this->relatedInvoices->isNotEmpty()) {
            $this->invoice = $this->relatedInvoices->first(); // Set the primary invoice based on the latest update
        } else {
            // If no invoices found, initialize $this->invoice to null
            $this->invoice = null;
        }

        // Handle the paid status based on the related invoices, ensuring $this->invoice is not null
        if ($this->invoice) {
            $this->invoice->paid_status = $this->relatedInvoices->every(function ($relatedInvoice) {
                return $relatedInvoice->is_paid == 2;
            }) ? "paid" : ($this->relatedInvoices->contains(function ($relatedInvoice) {
                return $relatedInvoice->is_paid == 0;
            }) ? "unpaid" : "transfer");
        }
    }

    public function downloadInvoice($invoiceId)
    {
        return redirect()->route('invoice.downloadPdf', ['id' => $invoiceId]);
    }

    public function downloadReceipt($invoiceId)
    {
        return redirect()->route('invoice.downloadReceipt', ['id' => $invoiceId]);
    }
}


my invoice-detail.blade.php is:
<div>
    @if ($errorMessage)
        <p class="error-text">{{ $errorMessage }}</p>
    @endif
    <div class="questionnaire-top__left -fstart -mb">
        <h2 class="heading-primary">利用明細確認</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="usage__detail">
        <div class="fee-list__date-wpr">
            <div class="fee-list__date-select">
                <select class="date-selection-select" wire:model.live.debounce.300ms="year">
                    <option value="">-</option>
                    @foreach ($years as $yearOption)
                        <option value="{{ $yearOption }}" {{ $yearOption == $year ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                            {{ $yearOption }}
                        </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                <p class="date-selection-txt">年</p>
            </div>
            <div class="fee-list__date-select">
                <select class="date-selection-select" wire:model.live.debounce.300ms="month">
                    <option value="">-</option>
                    @for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++)
                        <option value="{{ $i }}" {{ $i == $month ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                            {{ $i }}
                        </option>
                    @endfor
                </select>
                <p class="date-selection-txt">月</p>
            </div>
        </div> 
        @if($invoice)
        <div class="usage__content">
            <h2 class="usage__title">{{$year}}年{{$month}}月分 ご利用料金</h2>
            <div class="usage__button">
                <div class="usage__button-wpr">
                    @if($invoice!=null && $invoice->paid_status == "paid")
                        <p class="usage__content-desc">{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($invoice->payment_date)->format('Y年m月d日') }}　入金済み</p>
                    @elseif($invoice->paid_status == "transfer")
                        <p class="usage__content-desc">{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($invoice->payment_date)->format('Y年m月d日') }}　振込済み</p>
                    @else
                        <div class="basic__calendar">
                            <div class="basic__calendar-input">
                                <input type="text"
                                        class="calendar flatpickr-input invoice-calendar active"
                                        wire:model.live.debounce.300ms="paymentDate" readonly="readonly">
                                <span class="calendar-icon -new"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-release modalOpen" wire:loading.attr="disabled" data-target="modal-invoice-payment">振込完了</a>
                    @endif
                </div>
                @if($invoice->paid_status == "unpaid")
                    <p class="usage__content-note">※振込が終わりましたらボタンを押してください</p>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
        @endif
        <div class="usage__table">
            <div class="usage__table-wpr">
                <table class="table -usage">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="table-row -transparent">
                            <th class="table-heading -nosort">項目</th>
                            <th class="table-heading -nosort">ご利用回数</th>
                            <th class="table-heading -nosort">単価（税込）</th>
                            <th class="table-heading -nosort">金額（税込）</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @php
                            $totalAmount = 0; // Initialize total amount
                        @endphp
                        @forelse ($relatedInvoices as $relatedInvoice)
                            <!-- Multiple related invoices -->
                            <tr class="table-row -transparent">
                                <td class="table-cell">{{ $relatedInvoice->survey->name }}</td>
                                <td class="table-cell">1</td>
                                <td class="table-cell">¥{{ number_format($relatedInvoice->amount) }}</td>
                                <td class="table-cell">¥{{ number_format($relatedInvoice->amount) }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @php
                            $totalAmount += $relatedInvoice->amount; // Add each invoice amount to total
                        @endphp
                        @empty
                            <tr class="table-row">
                                <td class="table-cell" colspan="4">{{ __('No search results found') }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforelse
                            <!-- Display the total amount -->
                            <tr class="table-row -transparent">
                                <td class="table-cell -bold" colspan="3">ご請求額合計</td>
                                <td class="table-cell -bold -fz16">¥{{ number_format($totalAmount) }}</td>
                            </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        @if($invoice)
            <div class="usage__footnote">
                <div class="usage__footnote-left">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_blank" class="btn-primary" wire:click="downloadInvoice({{ $invoice->id }})">請求書をダウンロードする</a>
                    @if($invoice->is_invoice_downloaded)
                    <p class="usage__footnote-circle">請求書ダウンロード済</p>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="usage__footnote-right">
                    @if($invoice->paid_status == "paid")
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_blank" class="btn-primary -sec" wire:click="downloadReceipt({{ $invoice->id }})">領収書をダウンロードする</a>
                        @if($invoice->is_receipt_downloaded)
                            <p class="usage__footnote-circle">領収書ダウンロード済</p>
                        @endif
                    @endif
                        <p class="usage__footnote-txt">※当月分を月末までの入金で15日発行/ 翌月15日までの入金で月末に発行</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            {{-- modal start --}}
            <div class="modal modal-del" wire:loading.remove id="modal-invoice-payment">
                <div class="modal-inner">
                    <form class="modal-form">
                        <h2 class="modal-title">{{ __('Transfer payment') }}</h2>
                        <p class="modal-que">{{ __('Are you sure you want to complete transfer?') }}</p>
                        <div class="modal-btns-wpr">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-submit -return">キャンセル</a>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" wire:click="transferPayment({{ $invoice->id }})" class="btn-submit -confirm">はい</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            {{-- modal end --}}
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="snippet loading" wire:loading.flex>
        <p class="loading__para">{{ __('Loading, please wait ') }}</p>
        <div class="stage">
            <div class="dot-pulse"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Here my js  code is in app.js so modal is also working in normal case.
So what is the possible solution to make calendar and modal open work?
